# "virsh vcpupin" and CPU isolation in ESXi

Tags: cpu, kvm, esxi, vcpu

I am trying to run an application within a VM on ESXi. The application runs a highly latency sensitive thread. It runs in tight polling mode which almost always runs at 99.9% of the CPU and this is expected.

Details of the VM and server:

```
Number of vCPUs allocated to the VM: 36
Number of sockets: 2
Number of cores per socket: 10
Total number of logical CPUs on the server: 40
Hyper threading : Enabeld
ESXi version: 6.50
```

If nothing else is run on the VM, there is no problem. But if I run other CPU consuming applications on the VM, the thread I talked about earlier starts getting lesser CPU cycles. I have verified this by adding some counters that calculate `rdtsc()`

On KVM, this can be solved by:

- Pinning the vCPU to physical cpu with `virsh vcpupin <domain> ...`
- Pinning the applications on the VM to run on specific vCPUs

How does the ESX CPU scheduler work? Is there a way to map vCPUs to physical cpus on ESXi?

When I monitor `esxtop` on the host, I see that the thread that takes 99.9% CPU does not always run on the same core. It keeps moving around different cores. And a few times, I see that it shares the physical core with other CPU intensive applications.

Comment: https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-4-esx-vcenter/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.vsphere.resourcemanagement.doc_41/managing_cpu_resources/c_using_cpu_affinity.html  Maybe?

Comment: I have tried that. This only changes the set of CPUs the VM can use. There is no control over the CPU pinning from inside the guest

Comment: You can prefer to https://serverfault.com/questions/1050436/set-cpu-affinity-for-specific-vm-on-vmware-esxi-using-govc-cli
Hope it can help